# Projective dimension of a principal ideal

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a polynomial ring, $I$ a homogeneous ideal, and let $\operatorname{pd}(R/I)$ denote its projective dimension.  Is there a characterization of homogeneous elements $a\in R\setminus I$ for which we have strict inequality:
$$(\dagger) \ \ \operatorname{pd}(R/I)<\operatorname{pd}(R/(I+(a)))?$$
For example I think that if $a$ is not a zero divisor for $R/I$ then $(\dagger)$ holds by Corollary 4.3.14 in Weibel's book.  I'm wondering if there are other examples of $a$'s where $(\dagger)$ holds?  Or is it an if and only if, i.e. $(\dagger)$ holds if and only if $a$ is a nonzero divisor for $R/I$?  Any examples or references or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take $R=k[x,y]$, $I=(x^2,xy)$ and $a=x$. Then projective dimension of $R/I=2$, projective dimension of $R/I+(a)=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the example!  I guess I'm particularly interested in examples where $(\dagger)$ does hold, especially if its a zero divisor if $R/I$.  Still, thanks :-)

Comment: The same example works. Take $I=(x^2), a=xy$ (or the other way works too). Then projective dimension of $R/I=1$, $xy$  is a zero divisor in $R/I$ and projective dimension of $R/(x^2,xy)=2$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's already been answered in the comments.

Comment: Hmmm...well I guess I got one example, but the question whether there is a characterization of such a's has certainly not been settled...